# i am new to this html and css coding and its not recognizing the mp3,how can i code it to recognize it?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to code an audio player in my html but it doesnt seem to recognize the audio thus being not avialable to play.....i am new to html and css coding . i followed the w3school type but its not working can anyone help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1{
 background-color:lightblue;
 text-align:center;
 border-radius:16px;
}
p{
 font-family:verdana;
 outline-color:red;
 text-align:center;
}
button{
 background-color:yellow;
 padding:16px 32px;
 text-align:center;
 border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:-57px 220px;
    color:black;
}
button{
 border-radius:15px;
}
body{
 background-color:orange;
}
h3{
  background-color:lightgreen;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:50px;

}
audio{
  margin:-67px 156px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>WELCOME TO MY WEBSITE<h1>
  <p>plz decode this message to view it 
   _...  ....  _ _ _  _ _ _  _  _.  ..  
   use the button below to refer to cheatsheet</p>
   <a href="https://www.boxentriq.com/img/morse-code/morse-code-overview.png"><button>Click here</button></a>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="hen.ogg" 
       type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="hen.mp3" 
        type="audio/mpeg">
   </audio>
</html>
</body>
```

**strong text**

Comment: your snippet doesn't work because `https://stacksnippets.net/hen.ogg` (and the mp3 version) were not found! Do you get similar errors when running locally. Make sure the `src` attributes actually resolve to where the files can be found!

Answer (score 0):

Not enough rep to comment but what browser are you using and where do you store the mp3 file? You can try something like this to check browser compatibility. You should not be able to see the text if all works fine.

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="hen.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="hen.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  No browser support.
</audio>
```

Comment: I am using google chrome and i saved the mp3 file on my dekstop , and its working ....the coding has worked plus the audio player came as an output but i cant click the play button because it doesn’t seem to get that file...idk

Comment: If you are using files such as audio or images you need to place them in the same folder as your html. Your code will search for a hen.mp3 file in the same folder as your html.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1{
    background-color:lightblue;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:16px;
}
p{
    font-family:verdana;
    outline-color:red;
    text-align:center;
}
button{
    background-color:yellow;
    padding:16px 32px;
    text-align:center;
    border:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:-57px 220px;
    color:black;
}
button{
    border-radius:15px;
}
body{
    background-color:orange;
}
h3{
  background-color:lightgreen;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:50px;

}
audio{
  margin:-67px 156px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>WELCOME TO MY WEBSITE<h1>
  <p>plz decode this message to view it
    _...  ....  _ _ _  _ _ _  _  _.  ..
    use the button below to refer to cheatsheet</p>
    <a href="https://www.boxentriq.com/img/morse-code/morse-code-overview.png"><button>Click here</button></a>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="hen.ogg"   <!-- Audio file must be in the same folder
                                           as your HTML file -->
       type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="voice/hen.mp3" <!-- If they are not in the same folder then,
                                    specify it like this -->
        type="audio/mpeg">
   </audio>
</html>
</body>
[When your audio is not in the same folder as your HTML file][1]


[When your audio is in the same folder as your HTML file][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Rzm.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQk3V.png
```

Comment: i'm glad to hear that ^^